# reledmac + reledpar: familiar notes called on the left side, but to be printed on the right side

Tags: footnotes, reledmac, reledpar

I am using `reledpar` to have a Latin text with facing Italian translation. I would like to have critical footnotes on the left page, under the Latin text, and familiar footnotes with commentary to the Latin text on the right page, under the Italian translation, but with footnotemarks in the Latin text. So, the opposite of what is described in § 6.3.5 of the reledpar manual.

I tried reversing the commands `\footnoteXnomk` and `footnoteXmk` but it doesn’t work. Is there a way to achieve this or should I open an issue on GitHub?

MWE:

```
% !TEX encoding = utf8
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage{latin}

\usepackage[series={A},noend,noledgroup,nopbinverse]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pages}
        \begin{Leftside}
            \begin{latin}
            \beginnumbering
            \setstanzaindents{0,0}
            \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1} 
            \begin{astanza}
                Arma uirumque cano, Troiae\footnoteA{Troja chiamata ancora Ilo, e Dardania…} qui primus ab oris&        
                Italiam fato profugus \edtext{Lauiniaque}{\Afootnote{Lauinaque}} uenit&
                Litora, multum ille et terris iactatus et alto&
                Vi superum, saeuae memorem Iunonis ob iram,&
                Multa quoque et bello passus, dum conderet urbem&
                Inferretque deos Latio, genus unde Latinum&
                Albanique patres atque altae moenia Romae.\&
            \end{astanza}
            \endnumbering
            \end{latin}
        \end{Leftside}
        \begin{Rightside}
            \beginnumbering
            \numberlinefalse
            \pstart
                Canto l’armi, e l’Eroe, che fuggendo da’ lidi di Troja per voler del fato, il primo portossi in Italia, e alle spiagge di Lavinio. Molto fu egli agitato in terra, ed in mare dal supremo poter degli Dei, a cagione del tenace sdegno della crudel Giunone, e molto ancora soffrì in guerra, finché fabbricasse una città, ed introducesse gli Dei nel Lazio; donde presero origine la stirpe de’ Latini, i primi cittadini di Alba, e le mura della superba Roma.
            \pend
            \endnumbering
        \end{Rightside}
    \end{pages}
    \Pages
\end{document}
```

I would like the note on *Troiae* to be on the right page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Preamble

As explained in the handbook, you should not use anymore the `\numberlinefalse` setting which is bugged (and created bug in your case !). Use instead a hight value for first line number : `\firstlinenumR{1000000}`.

## Solution for your problem

Just switch Leftside and Rightside environnement order.

## Example

```
% !TEX encoding = utf8
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage{latin}

\usepackage[series={A},noend,noledgroup,nopbinverse]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\firstlinenumR{1000000}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pages}
        \begin{Rightside}
            \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Canto l’armi, e l’Eroe, che fuggendo da’ lidi di Troja\footnoteAnomk{Troja chiamata ancora Ilo, e Dardania…} per voler del fato, il primo portossi in Italia, e alle spiagge di Lavinio. Molto fu egli agitato in terra, ed in mare dal supremo poter degli Dei, a cagione del tenace sdegno della crudel Giunone, e molto ancora soffrì in guerra, finché fabbricasse una città, ed introducesse gli Dei nel Lazio; donde presero origine la stirpe de’ Latini, i primi cittadini di Alba, e le mura della superba Roma.
            \pend
            \endnumbering
        \end{Rightside}
        \begin{Leftside}
            \begin{latin}
            \beginnumbering
            \setstanzaindents{0,0}
            \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
            \begin{astanza}
                Arma uirumque cano, Troiae\footnoteAmk qui primus ab oris&
                Italiam fato profugus \edtext{Lauiniaque}{\Afootnote{Lauinaque}} uenit&
                Litora, multum ille et terris iactatus et alto&
                Vi superum, saeuae memorem Iunonis ob iram,&
                Multa quoque et bello passus, dum conderet urbem&
                Inferretque deos Latio, genus unde Latinum&
                Albanique patres atque altae moenia Romae.\&
            \end{astanza}
            \endnumbering
            \end{latin}
        \end{Leftside}
    \end{pages}
    \Pages
\end{document}
```